# DataGridView in windows 10 shows columns that have visible set to false programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows-10

I am wondering if anyone has come across an issue with Windows 10 (using the Enterprise edition) in which an application all of a sudden is showing all columns in a standard datagridview even though the columns have visible set to false in the code behind.  This application works fine and has been in production now for over a year, and is running on windows 7, 8 and 8.1 without any issues.  The moment it was placed on the 10 machine, it worked, but the datagridviews are showing all columns!

I have set the compatibility to both 7 and 8 but it still has the same behavior.

The code has not changed in a year.

I have googled for this error and have come up with nothing so far.

So has anyone else had this issue?

The application is using the 4.5 framework and is a windows form application.

The code is very straight forward for this:

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

So again, nothing has changed except for the machine being tested on.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try on an 7-8.1 machine with .net 4.6 installed.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

1. Moved the hidden column to the end of the columns list in the designer.
2. Programatically setting the datagridview.coulumns[datagridcolumnd.name].visible = false